# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4'

Tags: tensorflow

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4' while building tensorflow from source. I have used bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package to build it

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `--copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4"` to your command line as this is not a flag gcc supports.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I am compiling under x86(build server machine running with ubuntu 14.04 LTS) but I want .whl image for armv7l. I followed https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md as it looked similar. while following the steps mentioned here I got this error.

Comment: so what will be option to for neon support during tensorflow compilation in arm. it fails in arm-gcc also.

Answer (score 0):

This flag is used on ARM architectures. If you are compiling under x86/amd64, just remove it.

```
$ gcc -mfpu=neon-vfpv4
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mfpu=neon-vfpv4
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I am compiling under x86(build server machine running with ubuntu 14.04 LTS) but I want .whl image for armv7l. I followed https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md as it looked similar.

Comment: Then you should either use cross-compiler or build it on ARM machine.

Comment: I tried to cross compile by following https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain but all the BUILD and CROSSTOOL files(added for arm compilation) are getting deleted after giving "bazel build <> <> "                                                                    Is it possible to get tensorflow wheel package with unicode 2 for armv7l ?